# Open file to edit problems

Tags: php, file

Using `opendir` I am displaying a list of files in a folder. Each file is a `<a href>` link.

I am trying to open a file in edit mode when name of the file is clicked but it seems that  I hit a bump and can't get it to work. When I click a file it goes to the edit page but it is not selecting the file to be edited so it does not open.

Can anyone advise me how I can select the file?

This is my code to display all the files in the folder:

```
$directory = 'source';

if ($handle = opendir($directory. '/')) {
  echo 'Looking inside \''.$directory.'\'<br><br>';
  while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      echo '<form method="post" action="file5.php">';
      // echo '<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" name="fileName">'.$file.'</a><br>';
      echo '<a href="file5.php" name="name">'.$file.'</a>';
      echo '</form>';
    }   
  } 
}
```

and then in this part using include the file should open in edit mode:

**EDIT**

This is the rest of the form that i am using:

```
   include filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fileName', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



 echo '<form action="updatefile.php" method="post">';
   echo '<div class="create_field">';   
  foreach($_ as $part1 => $part2)
    {
       echo trim('<p><textarea name="content_prt1[]" rows="2" cols="50">'.str_replace($simbols, "",$part1).'</textarea> <textarea name="content_prt2[]" rows="2" cols="50">'.str_replace($simbols, "",$part2).'</textarea></p>');
    }


  echo '</div>';
  echo'<input type="button" id="button" value="Create New Element"/>';
 ?>

 <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="name">

<?php
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Exit" name="Exit">';
  echo '<form />';
?>
```

tnx for the help in advance

Comment: this form is wrong, there are not submit button and you always send file5.php.. that code should be  echo '<a href="'.$file.'" name="name">'.$file.'</a>';

Comment: i do have the submit button i only posted the code where i am getting an error that the file is not selecting if you want i can post the rest of the file

Comment: Your code is confusing. Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. I think you need one form to list the files, so people can choose one. Then the file opens in another from where edits can be made.

Comment: I am trying to open the selected file to be edited. Is there a function that i can use or something to pass the selected files name to include ? i should have probably used this question sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its make a form whit radio buttom.

```
$directory = 'source';

if ($handle = opendir($directory. '/')) {
  echo 'Looking inside \''.$directory.'\'<br><br>';
  while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      echo '<form method="get" action="file5.php">';
      // echo '<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" name="fileName">'.$file.'</a><br>';
      echo '<input name="name" value="'.$file.'" type="radio">'.$file.'<br>';

    }   

  } 
  echo '<input class="button" type="submit" name="send" value="send"></form>';
}
```

Edit.

In file5.php, you should have something like this to open the file an edit it:

```
if(isset($_GET['send'])){

    $file=source.'/'.$_GET["name"];

$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
$data = fread($handle,filesize($file));
 echo "<form action=""  method=post>";
 echo "File text<br>";
 echo "<textarea name='file_text' rows='10' cols='40' id='elm1'>".$data."</textarea><br>";
 echo "<input class=button type=submit name=send value=send><br></form>";

}
```

Comment: tnx for the post i was asked to use include insted of fopen and fread i have done this with fopen and fread and it worked but when i changed to include it dose not work.

Comment: tnx for your help using your example i solved my problem tnx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $directory = 'source';

if ($handle = opendir($directory. '/')) {
  echo 'Looking inside \''.$directory.'\'<br><br>';
  echo '<select name='name'>
  while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      echo '<form method="get" action="file5.php">';
      // echo '<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" name="fileName">'.$file.'</a><br>';
      echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
    } 
  } 
  echo '</select>';
  echo '<input class="button" type="submit" name="send" value="send">;
  echo '</form>';
}
```